# How to locate a backslash in R

Tags: r

I want to locate a backslash in a string.

I have a below string with first character as a backslash.

I am using str_locate from stringr package. I am using below code.

```
library(stringr)    
test_string <- "\",Product ID,[\""
str_locate(test_string, pattern =  "\\\\")
```

Output:

```
> str_locate(test_string, pattern =  "\\\\")
     start end
[1,]    NA  NA
```

I am expecting the character position.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the string itself.

```
test_string <- "\\"
stringr::str_locate(test_string, pattern =  "\\\\")

#     start end
#[1,]     1   1
```

---

For the updated question, you don't actually have backslash in your string, backslash is a way in R to escape quotes (`"`). You can view the actual string by using `cat`

```
cat(test_string)
#",Product ID,["
```

As we can see there is no backslash in the string hence the result is `NA`.

Comment: Hi Ronak, I have only one backslash in the string. I have the string like this. '\",Product ID,[\"'. Editing my question

Comment: @Prafulla There is no backslash in your string. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is where I am facing a problem. The text file I have received has backslash like I have mentioned and I have to locate them all.

Comment: @Prafulla Can you see those backslashes in the text file? Open it in Notepad or any other text editor and see if you have those backslashes which you are seeing it in R.

Comment: Hi Ronak, Yes, I can see the backslash in the Notepad. With the cat() I cannot see but with the variable I can see

Comment: If you cannot see them with `cat` I doubt if they are actually present. They are definitely not present in the updated `test_string` you shared. Run few of these examples in the console to understand how backslashes and single quotes are represented. `cat("\"")`, `cat("\\\"")` In the second example the first backslash is to escape the backslash (at 2nd position) whereas third backslash is to escape single quotes.

Comment: @RonakShah, shouldn't you use `str_locate_all` for the OP's example? Since OP wants to locate any number of backlashes.

Comment: @cimentadaj yes, ideally `str_locate_all` would give location of all the matches but I think OP has some different issue.